# Tem como uma macro criar outra macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Eu tenho uma planilha de analistas, porém, quando muda o analista ou entra algum novo eu preciso copiar tudo igual dos outros analistas apenas mudando o nome dele. Eu queria saber se existe a possibilidade de eu criar uma macro que cria uma macro com o nome do novo analista digitado pelo usuário.

**Edição**

```
Sub Victor()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call limpaFiltro
Call resetEmail(Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call BuscaBasePenhoras("Victor ", "Pendente", Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call BuscaPendencias("Victor ", Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call ExibePendenciasDaAgenda(Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call ExibePendenciaAgendaNoEmail(Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call acoesPro("Victor ", "Pendente", "ACAO PRO", Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call ExibeTextoAcaoPro(Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call ExibeAcoesProNoEmail(Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call PendenciasNoEmail(Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call EmAnalise("Victor ", "Em Análise", Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call REDLINE("Victor ", "xAtualizado", Sheets("Email_Victor"))
Call ClearClipboard

End Sub
```

Eu quero fazer a função de outro analista. Mas quero que seja feita pelo usuário. Quero que quando ele clique em um botão "Add Analista" abra um inputBox que pegue só o nome do analista, e sozinho ele cria um novo módulo com o nome do analista, copia esse código dentro do módulo e altera os campos onde tem o nome `victor` para o nome inserido via inputBox.

Espero que dê pra entender.

Comment: Olá. Por favor, forneça mais detalhes, pois do jeito que a pergunta está dificilmente alguém conseguirá te ajudar. Hoje você faz isso manualmente? Vc simplesmente copia o arquivo e altera seu nome? Se não, onde você armazena o nome do analista?

Comment: @Alexandre, coloque uma imagem de como é a planilha e como deveria ficar, talvez nem seja preciso Macro para fazer o que você quer, ajude-nos a entender direito sua dificuldade e vamos ser mais assertivos na resposta.

Comment: Aparentemente, pela descrição do seu problema, você está usando uma abordagem inadequada para resolvê-lo. Você está fazendo um módulo pra cada Analista, enquanto deveria ter um módulo para atender todos Analistas. Enfim, você deveria ter Funções (Function) e Sub (Procedimentos) que atendessem qualquer analista. É como em qualquer programa, você escreve as rotinas que vão operarar sobre os dados e não uma rotina pra cada dado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sou um especialista em VBA, mas acho que consegui resolver seu problema utilizando o código disponível [aqui](http://vba4all.com/programmatically-create-a-vba-standard-module-and-write-code-to-it/).

Antes de testar, duas configurações precisam ser feitas:

1. No projeto VBA, adicionar a referência `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Na planilha, ir em Opções -> Central de Confiabilidade -> Configurações da Central de Confiabilidade -> Configurações de Macro -> selecionar Confiar no Acesso ao modelo de objeto do projeto do VBA

Feito isso, adicione o seguinte código a um módulo:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Adicionar_Analista()

    Dim moduleName As String
    moduleName = addModule
    WriteToModule moduleName, CStr("")

End Sub

Private Function addModule() As String
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    Dim macro As String
    Dim nome As String

    nome = InputBox("Nome do Analista")

    Dim vbDQ As String
    vbDQ = """"

    macro = "Sub " & nome & "()" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call limpaFiltro" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call resetEmail(Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call BuscaBasePenhoras(" & vbDQ & nome & " " & vbDQ & ", " & vbDQ & "Pendente" & vbDQ & ", Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call BuscaPendencias(" & vbDQ & nome & " " & vbDQ & ", Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call ExibePendenciasDaAgenda(Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call ExibePendenciaAgendaNoEmail(Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call acoesPro(" & vbDQ & nome & " " & vbDQ & ", " & vbDQ & "Pendente" & vbDQ & ", " & vbDQ & "ACAO PRO" & vbDQ & ", Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call ExibeTextoAcaoPro(Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call ExibeAcoesProNoEmail(Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call PendenciasNoEmail(Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call EmAnalise(" & vbDQ & nome & " " & vbDQ & ", " & vbDQ & "Em Análise" & vbDQ & ", Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call REDLINE(" & vbDQ & nome & " " & vbDQ & ", " & vbDQ & "xAtualizado" & vbDQ & ", Sheets(" & vbDQ & "Email_" & nome & vbDQ & "))" & vbCrLf _
        & vbTab & "Call ClearClipboard" & vbCrLf _
    & "End Sub"

    CodeMod.AddFromString macro

    addModule = VBComp.Name
End Function

Private Sub WriteToModule(moduleName As String, arrayName As String)
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(moduleName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 2, ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Para rodar, basta chamar a Sub. Por exemplo, com um botão:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Adicionar_Analista
End Sub
```

Será aberta uma InputBox pedindo o nome do analista.

Como o código que será escrito na Sub está dentro de uma string, é importante tomar alguns cuidados:

- As aspas que vão pra sub dinâmica não podem ser explicitas, você pode colocar `""""` ou, como eu fiz, utilizar uma variável para facilitar a leitura.
- Todas as linhas tem que terminar com `& vbCrLf _` para pular a linha e concetenar a string

Cada analista será adicionado em um novo módulo (deve ser possível juntar tudo em um só alterando o código).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, era exatamente isso.